# Use igraph (in R) to calculate conditional paths

Tags: r, igraph

I have graph network with edge weights and timestamp attribute on each edge. The part_data is data.frame contain the follow columns:

```
vertix_1, to_vertix_2, weight, time_vertix_1, time_vertix_2
```

The code for generating the graph is:

```
nodes=unique(unlist(part_data[,list(vertix_1, vertix_2)]))
graph1 = graph_from_data_frame(d = part_data[, list(vertix_1, vertix_2, weight, time_vertix_1, time_vertix_2)], vertices = nodes_all, directed = T)
```

I need to calculate all paths from vertix_1 to vertix_2 with condition time_vertix_2 of vertix_1 is less than time_vertix_1 of to_vertix_2.

Is there a simple way to calculate this?